# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a single page blogging site using AngularJS and  I have encountered the following error message:

***"Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module spBlogger due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module spBlogger.posts due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider"***

I'm not sure why this is happening although the $stateProvider service is already injected. Can you please help me identify why I'm getting this error message?

postModule.js contents:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('spBlogger.posts', ['spBlogger.posts.controllers', 'spBlogger.posts.directives', 'spBlogger.posts.services', 'spBlogger.posts.filters']);

angular.module('spBlogger.posts')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('allPosts', {
            url: '/posts',
            templateUrl: 'modules/posts/views/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostController'
        });
        $stateProvider.state('singlePost', {
            url: '/posts/:id/:permalink',
            templateUrl: 'modules/posts/views/singlePost.html',
            controller: 'PostDetailsController'
        });
}]);
```

index.html contents:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="spBlogger">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title>The Single Page Blogger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="modules/posts/css/posts.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br/>
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>The Single Page Blogger</h1>
            <p>One stop blogging solution</p>
        </div>
        <div ui-view> The angular ui-view should be displayed here!</div>
        <div class="row footer">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <p>The Single Page Blogger
                    <app-version/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- build:js app/built/app.min.js -->

<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>


<script src="modules/posts/postModule.js"></script>
<script src="modules/posts/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="modules/posts/js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="modules/posts/js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="modules/posts/js/services.js"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->

</html>
```

This is the app.js

```
'use strict'

angular.module('spBlogger', ['ui.router', 'spBlogger.posts', 'spBlogger.controllers', 'spBlogger.directives', 'spBlogger.filters', 'spBlogger.services']);

angular.module('spBlogger').value('version', 'V1.0');


angular.module('spBlogger').run(['state', function (state) {
    $state.go('allPosts');
}]);
```

controllers.js

```
'use strict'

angular.module('spBlogger.posts.controllers', [])


.controller('PostController', ['$scope', 'postService', function ($scope, postService) {
    $scope.getAllPosts = function () {
        return postService.getAll();
    };
    $scope.posts = $scope.getAllPosts();

}])


.controller('PostDetailsConstroller', ['$stateParams', '$state', '$scope', 'postService', function ($stateParams, $state, $scope, postService) {

    $scope.getPostById = function (id) {
        return postService.getPostById(id);
    };


    $scope.closePost = function () {
        $state.go('allPosts');
    };

    $scope.singlePost = $scope.getPostById($stateParams.id);
}])


;
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to add a dependency to `ui.router` in your application module:

```
angular.module('spBlogger.posts', ['ui.router', 'spBlogger.posts.controllers', 'spBlogger.posts.directives', 'spBlogger.posts.services', 'spBlogger.posts.filters']);
```

*Angular UI Router* isn't part of official Angular's distribution but it's an optional module developed by a third-party dev team.

Comment: @Maz But this could be who knows where in some controller, am I mistaken?

Comment: @Maz I believe I've already gave you a good hint on how to solve these issues. The error message is so clear. It's `$state` instead of `state`.

Comment: @Maz Use your mind! (Bruce Lee quotation.......). I don't see that the next error may be found in your sample code. BTW, double-check my comments and you should be able to solve the issue your self...